# A second operation started on this context, Domain Event EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-core-3.1

I'm using Domain Event to update some tables.
I have created a class that inherits INotificationHandlers like this:

```
  public class DamageTypeEvents:INotificationHandler<DamageTypeWasAddedEvent>,
                                INotificationHandler<AttributeWasUnlinkedEvent>,
                                INotificationHandler<AttributeWasLinkedEvent>
  {
    private readonly MyContext _writeContext;

    public DamageTypeEvents( MyContext writeContext )
    {
      _writeContext = writeContext;
    }
```

in app service I send a list of attributes and will link and unlink these attributes to DamageTypes.

```
public async Task Handle( AttributeWasUnlinkedEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
=>
//codes removed for brevity
await _writeContext.SaveChangesAsync( cancellationToken )

public async Task Handle( AttributeWasLinkedEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
=>
//codes removed for brevity
await _writeContext.SaveChangesAsync( cancellationToken )
```

when AttributeWasLinkedEvent fires, then it throws following error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation
> completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same
> instance of DbContext.

I think it can be fixed by using a DbContextFactory but EF Core 3.1 does not provide this feature.

**By the way if I change the DbContext lifetime to transient it will be fixed, but I am wondering if there is any other solution?**

**Update:**

here is how I use link and unlink in my entities.

```
//in command handler:
  .Check( x=>x.DamageType.UnlinkAttributes( x.Attributes ) )
  .Check( x=>x.DamageType.LinkAttributes(x.Attributes) )
  

//and in my entities

public Result LinkAttributes( List<Attribute> attributes )
    {
      var addedAttributes = attributes.Except( _attributes );
      _attributes.AddRange( addedAttributes );
      AddEvent( new AttributeWasLinkedEvent( Id));
      return Result.Success();
    }

    public Result UnlinkAttributes( List<Attribute> attributes )
    {
      var unlinkedAttributes = _attributes.Except( attributes );
      foreach ( var attribute in unlinkedAttributes ) {
         attribute.Delete();
         AddEvent( new AttributeWasUnlinkedEvent( Id,attribute.Id ));
      }
      return Result.Success();
    }
```

Comment: Switch to EF Core 6.0 and use `builder.Services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);` in your DepencyInjection initialization.

Comment: as I said I already did it in EF Core 3.1 and it works, no need to switch to EF Core 6.0, but I don't know using Transient will be thread safe or not.

Comment: Transient means an object will be created each time it is requested. That is the right way to go. Entity Framework by itself is not thread safe. But with each thread having it's own context there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by enabling Multiple Active Result Sets in your connection string:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" +
"Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +  
"MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

For reference: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets**

Comment: It's already set, but if I don't change the lifetime it will throw the error.